# Django: How to filter ForeignKey choices (e.g. with request.user) with ModelFormSet and FormWizard?

Tags: django, django-users, django-1.5, django-forms, django-formwizard

Having several ForeignKeys in a `ModelForm` that I want to use in a form wizard with `modelformset_factory` (not 100% sure about the formset) I'm wondering how to limit the choices of the dropdown field for I need to do it dynamically. I wanted to try it by writing my own modelformset factory but here on stackoverflow I read about other approaches but unfortunatelly I don't understand them.

That's how far I came:

models.py

```
#...
class Attendee(models.Model):
    """Event specific attendee details."""
    # event is set by URL.
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    attendee = models.ForeignKey(Person) # Contact details, should be limited to user
    accommodation = models.ForeignKey(Accommodation, blank=True) # *
    workshop = models.ForeignKey(Workshop, blank=True) # *
    volunteer = models.ForeignKey(Volunteer, blank=True) # *
    # *= should be limited to event but I think I will be able to handle that.
    #...

class AttendeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Attendee

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs): I tried this but I didn't get 
# it to work.
        super(AttendeeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
#         self.fields['attendee'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(owner=user)
        self.fields['workshop'].required = True
        #...

# This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858044/2704544 but I don't understand it. ##
def form_setup(**kwargs):
    def make_form(data, prefix=None, initial=None):
        form = (data, prefix, initial)
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k == 'some_list':
                form.fields['some_list'].choices = v # What does that mean?
            ...
        return form
    return make_form
#######################################################################################
```

([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858044/2704544) to source)

views.py

```
# This is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/623198/2704544 but I don't understand it. ###
class Callback(object):
    def __init__(self, field_name, aff):
        self._field_name = field_name
        self._aff = aff # What is this aff?
    def cb(self, field, **kwargs):
        nf = field.formfield(**kwargs)
        if field.name == self._field_name:  # this is 'options' field
            nf.queryset = ServiceOption.objects.filter(affiliate=self._aff)
        return nf
#######################################################################################

reg_wiz_forms = (
    ('attendees', modelformset_factory(Attendee, form=AttendeeForm, exclude='event', 
# formfield_callback=Callback('option', affiliate).cb Just copied. Why can you call 
# cb without arguments?
)),)
class RegWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_form_instance(self, step):
        instance = None

        if step == '0':
            instance = Attendees.objects.filter(owner__owner=self.request.user)
        #...
```

([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623198/2704544) to source)

urls.py

```
#...
url(r'^register/$', views.RegWizard.as_view(views.reg_wiz_forms), name='register'),
#...
```

I also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624013/2704544) about `curry` and other stuff and tried to override `get_initkwargs` and other methods of `WizardView` but I couldn't find any more docu or hints on that topic. Maybe someone can help me out.

### Update

It works partly with `curry` now. Partly because it doesn't work with a manage function:

views.py

```
def manage_wizard(request, event):
    AttendeeFormSet = modelformset_factory(Attendee, form=AttendeeForm, exclude='event')
    AttendeeFormSet.form = staticmethod(curry(AttendeeForm, user=request.user))
    wiz = RegWizard
    wiz.event = event
    return wiz.as_view([('attendees', AttendeeFormSet)])
```

I get an AttributeError: "'function' object has no attribute 'base_fields'" This sounds like the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624013/2704544).

But when I override `WizardView`'s `get_form_list` and call it in url.py directly it works:

```
reg_wiz_forms = ('attendees', modelformset_factory(Attendee, form=AttendeeForm, exclude='event'))

class RegWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_form_list(self):
        self.form_list['attendees'].form = staticmethod(curry(AttendeeForm, user=self.request.user))
        return super(RegWizard, self).get_form_list()
```

Now I'm wondering if there is a solution without overriding the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply want your foreign key queryset for the attendee attribute on your Model to be a filtered one on your ModelForm. You are on the right lines here:

```
self.fields['attendee'].queryset = Person.objects.filter(owner=user)
```

This is assuming an attribute 'owner' exists on the Person class.

This won't work however, as where or what is your user arg? One solution is to curry the forms **init** method, as you mention, to include the correct user object:

```
    form = staticmethod(curry(AttendeeForm, user=<the-user-obj>))
```

Now you pop your user arg from the kwargs in your **init** method:

```
user = kwargs.pop('user')
```

Now your filtered queryset will only display the Person you filtered for.

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs): I tried this but I didn't get 
it to work.
```

The line above won't work for a number of reasons, the primary being that it will never be called from anywhere, you are making a new function there, not overriding an existing one, which is what we are doing overring the **init** method.

Just some possibly helpful advice on design - You've got many threads here all providing many different ideas, complicating things a lot. Try to filter your problem to basic concepts. Here, it's a presentation of data issue, so think about starting in the Form, that's what it's there for. :-)

Comment: Now I could put it together. Then I tried to make a `manage_wizard` function to get the `request` and the event slug and create the ModelFormSets but think I have exactly the same problem as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/624013/2704544). Do you have any suggestion not to override `WizardView`'s `get_form_list` (which works)?

Comment: If you have another issue, I'd suggest posting your offending code in a new SO question so we can all take a look, this one's been answered.

Comment: Actually it's the same question. The funny thing is that I tried it first in the unconventional way (overriding). But I didn't like that so I tried to change it what failed. See update above for more details. Would you still post a new question? If, I could still do it but it had a similar title. I could also unaccept your answer.

Comment: I'd say the question has been answered, based on your title of the question 'how to filter Foreign Keys....'. My answer answers that. Your override method is absolutely valid, what makes you think overriding is 'unconventional'? It's 100% fine.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your patience :) Just for understanding: You wrote `def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):` won't work. I have this idea from [b-list](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/nov/09/dynamic-forms/). Did it work with Django 1.0 but not anymore?

Comment: It won't work for your case as you aren't calling your __init__ method from anywhere, the ModelForm gets instantiated in the guts of Django, as you are using the modelformset_factory. Hence the trick of adding to the kwargs instead of James Bennetts approach, which is fine for a custom form. You can see this by trying it; it will probably barf about __init__ taking 2 args, and I only have 1.